# PHP not working with WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I've downloaded WAMP server and I'm saving all PHP files to the dedicated directory for WAMP named 'www'. When I try and run a PHP file in a browser all I get is the PHP code even when doing echo statements I am using correct syntax, any thoughts?

Comment: Have you enclosed the PHP code using: `<?php` and `?>` ?

Comment: check the extension of the file, maybe it's file.php.txt

Comment: left click on wamp icon from system tray and click on Localhost, also check that your server is not offline

Comment: Are you accessing your scripts from the server's address ? (ex: [http://localhost/](http://localhost/)).

Comment: yep I sure am might just do a re-install, see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Try another Wamp package, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs for list.

Answer (score 0):

PHP.ini files add - `short_open_tag = On`